# How to exit properly from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The following will read and import many CSV files from disk into MongoDB but NodeJS won't exit after importing all the files if it doesn't go through the resizePhoto() function (Which contains a process.exit after resizing the images).

How can I have it to close properly after importing all files without interrupting? If I add a process.exit .on end it will exit after importing the first file.

```
var importData = function(fileName) {

    // Get file from disk.
    var filePath = path.join(folder, fileName);

    // Read and import the CSV file.
    csv.fromPath(filePath, {
        objectMode: true,
        headers: keys
    })
    .on('data', function (data) {

        var Obj = new models[fileName](data);

        models[fileName].find({}).remove().exec();

        Obj.save(function (err, importedObj) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(fileName, err);
            } else if (fileName === 'PHOTOS') {
                resizePhoto(importedObj);
            }
        });

    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log(fileName + ': Imported.');
    });
};

module.exports = importData;
```

Comment: Where does the csv variable come from?

Comment: Where's the code that calls this?  It seems like  you should add a callback to `importData()` and call that callback when the import is done and then the caller can do a `process.exit()` in that callback.

Comment: @aaaidan from fast-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the module **async**, method **parallel** (https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel). It can call your tasks (import) in parallel and call the final handler (exit) after all tasks end.

In your case:

**1) Somewhere in project**

```
csvImp=require('importData.js');
async.parallel([
    function(done){csvImp(name1,done);},
    function(done){csvImp(name2,done);},
    ...
    function(done){csvImp(nameN,done);}
],
function(err, results){
    process.exit();
});
```

**2) in importData.js**

```
var importData = function(fileName,done) {
...
.on('end', function() {
    console.log(fileName + ': Imported.');
    done();
});
```

So, next you need to prepare list of tasks. Something like

```
names.forEach(function(n){
    tasks.push(function(done){csvImp(n,done);});
});
```

And call **async.parallel** with **tasks**.

Good luck)